# Непонятка с Method could not be resolved в Eclipse.

Tags: jni, eclipse, android, android-ndk, c

Пишу следующий код в файле `HelloWorld.c`:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_ru_anya_helloworldndk_HelloWorld_messageFromNativeCode
(JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj)
{

return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello World from c!");
}
```

С помощью непосредственно ndk-build из консоли все собирается корректно. Из Eclipse же с NDK плагином на `NewStringUTF` показывает ошибку Method could not be resolved. Соответственно программа не запускается.

И что самое интересное! Если удалить эту ошибку из вкладки Problems, то программа успешно запускается, нужный метод выполняется, нет никаких ошибок. То есть нужный метод есть, все строится нормально, но ошибку при этом показывает. При этом напротив ошибки в коде стоит значок жука.

Сейчас отключила полностью ошибку Method could not be resolved, все работает, но тогда если метода и вправду не будет, такая ситуация не отловится.

Как решить эту проблему другим способом и в чем здесь дело?

Comment: Скорее всего Eclipse не видит заголовок jni.h. Попробуйте перейти (поставить курсор) на стоку с инклюдом и нажать F3(для того чтобы перейти в этот файл). Если не получится, то тогда нужно будет в настройках Eclipse прописать путь к этому хедеру.

Comment: Попробовала, файл показывает, берет из ndk.